# Minimize/Unminimize window with one shortcut

Tags: linux, bash, gnome

I am trying to set a shortcut key for:

1. xfce4-terminal to open (if its not already running)
2. IF running
3. Then check if its active
4. If Active then minimize it
5. If not active then show it (activate it)

By active I mean its open as an active window and not behind some other window.

For which I managed to write this script (Note: I do not know anything about bash scripting)

```
#!/bin/bash

if (ps aux | grep xfce4-terminal | grep -v grep > /dev/null)
then
    if([xfce4-terminal is active])
    then
       xdotool windowminimize [xfce4-terminal]
    else
       xdotool [activate xfce4-terminal] 
else
    xfce4-terminal
    exit 0
fi
```

Please note: anything enclosed in [] is what i want to achieve but have idea what command to use

Then I will save this script to a file and create a shortcut key to run this file and perform desired tasks

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/bash

if (ps aux | grep xfce4-terminal | grep -v grep > /dev/null)
then
    title=$(xdotool getactivewindow getwindowname)
    if [ "$title" = fullscreen ];
    then
        xdotool search --name fullscreen windowminimize
    else
        xdotool search --name fullscreen windowactivate
    fi    
else
    xfce4-terminal --title=fullscreen --fullscreen --hide-menubar
fi
```

DONE :)